# Why is the address of an array the same the array converted to a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-address

```
int t[10];

int * u = t;

cout << t << " " << &t << endl;

cout << u << " " << &u << endl;
```

Output:

```
0045FB88 0045FB88
0045FB88 0045FB7C
```

The output for `u` makes sense.

I understand that `t` and `&t[0]` should have the same value, but how come `&t` is also the same? What does &t actually mean?

Comment: ¤ The only difference between `t` converted to pointer, and `&t`, is the pointer type. The latter's referent is formally of array type, so that adding 1 to it moves it quite a bit (to the next such array in memory). While the former's referent is of the element type. Terminology: out in the [comp.lang.c++] Usenet group there was some controversy about whether a pointer like your `u` could be said to "point to" the array, since its referent is not of array type. That was resolved umpteen times by pointing to the standard's use of such wording. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: &u is a reference to the integer pointer, you normally use this as the argument of some function.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When `t` is used on its own in the expression, an array-to-pointer conversion takes place, this produces a pointer to the first element of the array.

When `t` is used as the argument of the `&` operator, no such conversion takes place. The `&` then explicitly takes the address of `t` (the array). `&t` is a pointer to the array as a whole.

The first element of the array is at the same position in memory as the start of the whole array, and so these two pointers have the same value.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose it was the implicit array-to-pointer conversion that gave me the wrong mindset of `u` being a pointer.

Comment: @quuxbazer: `u` _is_ a pointer. `t` _is_ an array. `int * u = t` applies an array-to-pointer conversion to `t`, and initialises `u` with the result.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I would be interested in the correct description in that case.

Comment: `(e ? a : n)` does not produce a pointer if both sides have the same array type for example.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I don't see how that invalidates this answer. Sure, there are some situations when array-to-pointer conversions do not take place. However, in this case they are occurring.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: The expression e3 = (e2 ? e1) doesn't make sense without e1 evaluating into a pointer, since there is no such thing such as an array assignment. The consequence of this is an array-to-pointer conversion having to take place and the alternative would be to leave out "e3 = ", which doesn't make sense, since the static evaluation would likely be elided away by the compiler or discarded by the dynamic (runtime) evaluation. In the case of e3 being passed to a pointer, again an array-to-pointer conversion would have to take place.

Comment: @Starhowl I did have cases like this in mind:  https://godbolt.org/z/caGcvqG6K Notice that the type of the span is `span<const int, 3>` ,therefore both sides were not converted to a pointer and that fact is useful.

Answer (score 5):

The actual type of `t` is `int[10]`, so `&t` is the address of the array.

Also, `int[]` implicitly converts to `int*`, so `t` *converts* to the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score -4):

There is no variable called `t`, since you can't change it. The name `t` simply refers to the address of the first element (and also has a size associated with it). Thus, taking the address of the address doesn't really make sense, and C "collapses" it into just being the address.

The same sort of thing happens for the case of functions:

```
int foo(void)
{
  return 12;
}

printf("%p and %p\n", (void *) foo, (void *) &foo);
```

This should print the same thing, since there is no variable holding the address of `foo`, whose address in turn can be taken.

Comment: It's C++, and there is variable called `t`. You can pass it to function which accepts argument with type `int(&)[10]`.

Comment: -1 "There is no variable called t, since you can't change it." is incorrect. An object that is named in a declaration is called a variable. Go look up the standard.