# Passing pointer to char array to function

Tags: c++

i had a little problem trying to pass the address for a character array to a function, here is a simple  example of what i am trying to do :

```
char a[20] = {"hello"};
printit( &a );
```

can you please give me the declaration of he printit function ( and maybe why ), i was expecting something like :

```
void printit( char ** value );
or void printit( char * value[] );
```

to work, but it is not.

*Error messages :

```
void printit( char ** value ); => cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[20]' to 'char **'
void printit( char * value[] ); => cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char (*)[20]' to 'char *[]'
```

thanks in advance.

Regards,
max.

Comment: What was the problem? (The error message)

Comment: Just telling us that it didn't work is not helpful. You need to tell us exactly what you tried, exactly what you expected it to do, and exactly what happened.

Comment: i have added the error message for each declaration.

Comment: For a print function of a string, the only declaration that makes sense is this: `void printit (const char* str);`. It is not clear to me whether printit is your own user-defined function or part of a library, however.

Comment: @Max  Maybe you wanted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array). Check out the selected answer. `&t` is a pointer to the array as whole, hence `int (*)[10]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parameter `&a` is a pointer to an array of 20 chars, hence:

```
void printit(char (*value)[20]);  // value is a pointer to an array of 20 chars
```

.

However, more commonly (especially with strings) would be to change the call into

```
printit(a);   // a will be passed as pointer to first elelemt, i.e. 'a' can be used as pointer to char
```

and define printit as

```
void printit(char *value)
{
     printf("The string is: %s", value);
}
```

Comment: as i understand , char a[2];// a is a pointer to the beginning of the array , so why do i have to give the size in the function declaration, and is there a way to pass it without the [20]

Comment: if you just pass 'a' as the parameter (as in my 2nd example) you can use it like a pointer to the first element of the array.  If you pass &a you need the [20].

Answer (score 1):

*Edited .. made a mistake

You are not declaring an array of char* you are declaring an array of char. Adding asterisk to your variable declaration and removing the & should make it work:

```
void printit(char** arr){
  string tmp(arr[0]);
  cout<<tmp<<endl;
}


char* a[20] = {"hello"};
printit( a );
```