# Difference between a, &a for int[][]

Tags: c++, types

When I run following program:

```
int a[3][4];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    a[i][j] = k++;

}

cout<<"a:  "<<a<<endl;
cout<<"&a: "<<&a<<endl;
```

output procudced is something like this:

> a:  002FFB4C  &a: 002FFB4C

Why are values same? should it not be different?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array

Comment: Why should the values be different? They have different types, isn't that enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, they can, but they need not - the C standard says nothing about the exact numerical value of pointers. By the way, I find it quite logical that they're the same - arrays are not pointers, so `a` can decay into a pointer to its first element, and `&a` is a pointer to `a`, which may quite obviously be the same as a pointer to its first element:

```
+------------------+------------------+- - - -
| 1st element of a | 2nd element of a |
+------------------+------------------+- - - -
^ pointer to first element
^ pointer to a (as well)
```

Comment: *"the C standard says nothing about the exact numerical value of pointers"*. I think it mandates (or it logically follows from the layout of array of arrays)?

Comment: @Nawaz As far as I remember, it only requires that the pointers are interchangeable **if "suitably converted"** (i. e. after typecasting).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `a` is the address of the first element of array of array — which is `a[0]`. Its address concides with the address of `a` itself.  Not only that it is same as `a[0]`, `&a[0]` and `&a[0][0]`.

Here is an interesting experiment:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define print(a) std::printf("%10s: %p\n", #a, a);

int main() 
{
    int a[3][4];
    print(&a);
    print(a);
    print(a[0]);
    print(&a[0]);
    print(&a[0][0]);
}
```

Output:

```
        &a: 0xbfafca80
         a: 0xbfafca80
      a[0]: 0xbfafca80
     &a[0]: 0xbfafca80
  &a[0][0]: 0xbfafca80
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/HZPFHX). :-)

Comment: I think you should mention that the standard doesn't mandate this, though.

Comment: @H: I think it mandates (or it logically follows from the layout of array of arrays)?