# Does the address of the array equal to that of its first element in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, language-lawyer, memory-address

This can be guaranteed in C because of the following sentence in WG14/N1570:

> 6.2.5/20 ... An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the element type.

But in WG21/N4527, i.e. in C++, the corresponding sentence becomes

> 8.3.4/1 ...An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set of N subobjects of type T.

while the word "describes" is changed to "contains", which cannot guarantee that the address of the array equals to that of its first element. Is this change intentional or unintentional? If it is intentional, does the address of the array equal to that of its first element in C++? If it does, which paragraph in the C++ standard can guarantee this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's stated explicitly anywhere, but I believe it follows from `5.3.3 Sizeof`:

> the size of an array of n elements is n times the size of an element

that the only thing that can be stored at the array's starting address is the array's first element.

Comment: Why it can be the last element? If I place subobjects in the reverse index order, it would change the size of an array?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't understand the question. The first element is the element with index zero.

Comment: @molbdnilo _The first element is the element with index zero_ Yep. Why does it have to be stored at the array's starting address?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ it is guaranteed by 4.2/1 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array], (bold by me)

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound
>   of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. **The result
>   is a pointer to the first element of the array.**

That means if you want to take the address of an array in C++, you would get a pointer which points to the first element of the array. i.e.

```
int a[10];
int* p1 = a;     // take the address of array
int* p2 = &a[0]; // take the address of the first element of the array
```

The standard guarantees that `p1` and `p2` will point to same address.

Comment: But this says nothing about the address of an array. It just says an array (**Neither its address nor a pointer to this array**) can be converted to a pointer to its first element. Even if it said a pointer to an array can be converted to a pointer to its first element, it does not say the conversion keeps the value stored in the pointer the same.

Comment: @Shenke I've added some explanation, as my understanding of the quoted standard.

Comment: The address of an array is simply `&a` in your example. So what I ask is whether `(void *)(&a) == (void *)a` is true.

Comment: @Shenke Sorry can't find the relevant content in the standard by now. And for reference only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array

Comment: It does not matter. Thanks anyway. @molbdnilo may give the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "address of array".

If you are asking if an array, when converted to a pointer, gives a result equal to the address of its first element, then the answer is yes.   For example;

```
#include <iostream>

void func(int *x, int *y)
{
     std::cout << "x and y are ";
     if (p != q) std::cout << "NOT ";
     std::cout << " equal\n";
}

int main()
{
    int x[2];

    func(x, &x[0]);
}
```

This will always report that the two pointers are equal.  songyuanyao has explained why.

However, `x` is not actually a pointer to an array (and nor is it converted to one in this code).    If you change the call of `func()` in `main()` to

```
  func(&x, &x[0]);
```

then that statement will not even compile.   The reason is that `&x` (the address of the array `x`) is not a pointer to an `int` - it is a pointer to an array of two `int`, and that cannot be implicitly converted into a pointer to `int`.

The value, however, will be the same, as may be demonstrated by running this code.

```
#include <iostream>

void func2(void *x, void *y)
{
     std::cout << "x and y are ";
     if (p != q) std::cout << "NOT ";
     std::cout << " equal\n";
}

int main()
{
    int x[2];

    func2(&x, &x[0]);     // both pointers implicitly converted to void * when calling func2()
}
```

Comment: Yes, what I want to ask is that why the two values stored in the two pointers are the same in the last code. I want to find an evidence in the C++ standard.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the C++ standard on my current machine, so can't look it up.   However, I do remember there are words to the effect that `&x` produces an address corresponding to the start point in memory of `x`   (i.e. where "start" means the smallest address of a byte that is part of the representation of `x`).

Comment: Yes, I know these words. But the trouble is why the start point of an array is its first element? Maybe there are something else (padding maybe, I don't know, or something meaningless just because the standard allows it) before its first element.

Comment: The alignment of an array is determined by the alignment of its elements.   One consequence of that is no padding before or between array elements.   Padding only (potentially) comes into play with structs or classes that have members of different sizes (and alignments).