# strlen returning wrong value for 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c-strings, strlen

Why is this:

```
char animals[][30] = {{"cow "}, {"dog "}, {"frog "}, {"gecko "}, {"cat"}};
```

returning 4 instead of 5 when I do this:

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(animals));
```

From what I believe, there are 5 different arrays of character arrays so i'm not sure why it is saying there are 4.

Comment: `animals` is NOT a string

Comment: You should be getting a warning about a type mismatch between `animals` and the argument of `strlen()`

Comment: `strlen` is short for "string length". Why would you expect that to return the number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 2):

This declaration

```
char animals[][30] = {{"cow "}, {"dog "}, {"frog "}, {"gecko "}, {"cat"}};
```

does not declare a one-dimensiobal array that contains a string.

The type of the argument of the function `strlen` shall be `char *`. But you are using an argument of the type `char ( * )[30]`.

What you need is the following

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( animals ) / sizeof( *animals ) );
```

> i'm not sure why it is saying there are 4.

Because in this call of `printf` that uses an invalid conversion specifier `%d` instead of `%zu`

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(animals));
```

the value of the argument `animals` in the call

```
strlen(animals)
```

is considered as the address of the first element of the array that indeed has the length equal to `4`.

That is from the point of view of equality of addresses this call

```
strlen(animals)
```

is equivalent to the call

```
strlen(animals[0])
```

because the value of `animals` used in the first call is equal to the value of the address of its first element `animals[0]`. Though in the first call of `strlen` the argument has an invalid type.

The compiler should issue a message that you are using an incorrect argument in the call of `strlen`.

Comment: Actually it's equivalent to `strlen(&animals[0])`.

Comment: @Barmar It is the same as animals[0]. All these expressions have the same value.

Comment: @Barmar It is required for all architectures. The address of an array is equal to the address of its first element.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow But that appears to be contradicted by [**6.2.5 Types**, p28](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28): "... Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."  The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647319/does-the-address-of-the-array-equal-to-that-of-its-first-element-in-c) even states there's no explicit requirement that the address of an array is equal to the address of its first element.  Seems like a good language-lawyer question.

Comment: @AndrewHenle An element type of an array is not an "another type" The address of a multidimensional array is the address of its first element and the address of the first element of that first element. All three values are equal each other and are the address of the extent allocated to the array..

Answer (score 1):

[`strlen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) is for calculating the length of strings (null-terminated sequence of characters in C), not for calculating the number of elements of array.

To obtain the number of elements in an array, you can divide the size of array by the size of an element of the array.

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(animals) / sizeof(*animals));
```

Also note that you should use `%zu`, not `%d`, to print `size_t` (`strlen()` and `sizeof` return `size_t`)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with the call `printf("%d\n", strlen(animals));`

- the `printf` format should be `%zu` if `strlen` has been properly declared by including `<string.h>` at the point of the call. This is unlikely to pose a problem but should be fixed.
- `strlen()` takes a C String and `animal` is not a C string, it is a 2D array of `char`. You should instead pass `strlen(animal[0])`. Again this mistake is unlikely to pose a problem because the address of the first string in the 2D array is the same as that of the array itself.  To compute the number of elements in the 2D array, use `sizeof(animal) / sizeof(*animal)`.
- the call should print `4` (the string `"cow "` has a trailing space) and a newline, and the return value will be `2` as the number of characters output by `printf`.

Try this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char animals[][30] = {{"cow "}, {"dog "}, {"frog "}, {"gecko "}, {"cat"}};

    printf("number of strings: %zu\n", sizeof(animals) / sizeof(*animals));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(animals) / sizeof(*animals); i++) {
        printf("%zu: \"%s\", %zu chars\n", i, animals[i], strlen(animals[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer to your question

"returning 4 instead of 5 when I do this"

when you do this

```
printf("%d\n", strlen(animals));
```

animals is a pointer to the first of the strings, animals is stored in memory as "cow \0........dog \0..." where ..... are bytes until the next array entry (usually random memory stuff if not initialized). When you printf strlen of animals it returns strlen of "cow ".

You are mixing types.. c allows this because they are pointers really, this is why compiler works but it is wrong.

to get 5 as result you will need to do this

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(animals) /sizeof(animals[0]));
```