# How to understand address for array of pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb

I have a simple program:

```cpp
int main(){
    int *p[2];

    p[0] = new int;
    p[1] = new int;
    *p[0] = 10;
    *p[1] = 12;

    delete p[0];
    delete p[1];
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ test.cpp -g -fno-stack-protector -o test
```

Using GDB to debug (break before variable destruction):

```
(gdb) x p
0x7fffffffdfc0: 0x5556aed0
(gdb) x &p
0x7fffffffdfc0: 0x5556aed0
(gdb) x p+1
0x7fffffffdfc8: 0x5556aef0
(gdb) x &p+1
0x7fffffffdfd0: 0xffffe0d0
```

So my question is:

1. Why `p` is same with `&p`？I think `p` means the start address of array, namely `&p[0]`, while `&p` stores the address of array. I thought they share no relationship.
2. Then as `p` equals `&p`, what defines the behavior for `+1`，why `p+1` is `&p[1]`, but `&p+1` is next address after `int *p[2]`.

Comment: The address of an array and the address of the first element of an array have the same value (only the type is different). And the answer to question 2 is the same `p` and `&p` have different types so `p+1` and `&p+1` have different values, because the pointer addition scales the addition depending on the underlying type.

Comment: @john you mean `+1` relys on the type of variable? Where is this information stored? Is this in some sections or just defined by compiler?

Comment: It's not stored anywhere, but it is used by the compiler (and by the debugger).

Comment: `ptr+1`, where `ptr` is of type `T`, is equivalent to `&(ptr[1])`. The numeric address of `ptr` is incremented by `sizeof(T)`. The actual value of `sizeof(T)` is computed at compile-time and the value is most likely directly embedded in the assembly instruction.

Comment: @CygnusX1 `sizeof(&p)` is 8 byte, why `&p+1` increments 16 bytes? Is this processed by g++ or gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an identifier of an array type appears in an expression other than `sizeof`, `address-of` (`&`), or initialization of a reference, it's converted to a `pointer` to the first array element. Therefore, `p` means `&p[0]`.

For `int *p[2]` the type of expression `&p` is `int* (*)[2]` pointer to array of 2 pointers to `int`.

`p+1` move to next array element (is equivalent `&p[0] + 1`) with increment `sizeof(int*)`

`&p+1` move to next array. Increment is `sizeof(p)` or `2 * sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: How did the answer justify that `p` is same as `&p` ?

Comment: Address of first element is `&p[0]`, which is equal to `p`, but how did that explain that `p` is same as `&p`

Comment: The address of the array (`&p`) is [equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647319/does-the-address-of-the-array-equal-to-that-of-its-first-element-in-c) to the address of its first element (`p`).

Comment: " **address of the array (&p)** "   I think `&p` is a pointer to an array of two `int` pointers.

Comment: `&p` is a pointer [to an array of two int pointers] that holds address.

Comment: In the previous comment, you mentioned `&p` as an array.    "The address of the array (&p) "

Comment: The value of  `&p` is the address of the array, And its type is a pointer to the array.