# Pointer and reference address

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain me why &p have the same address after I allocated memory.
And why p does not have the same address as: &p ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int *p;

   cout << "p value: " << *p << "   p adress: " << p << " &p reference: " << &p;

   p = new int;
   *p = 5;
   cout << endl;
   cout << "p value: " << *p << "   p adress: " << p << " &p reference: " << &p;

   return 0;

}
```

After compilation:

```
p value: -462058557   p adress: 0x74af73da &p reference: 0x6fff0c
p value: 5            p adress: 0x1d2978   &p reference: 0x6fff0c
```

Comment: `p` is the address the pointer is pointing to, `&p` is the actual address in memory where the pointer is stored

Comment: `&p` is not a reference, it's a pointer to `p`.

Comment: `&p` is an `int **`, not a reference, while `p` is an `int *` as declared. The "address of pointer is same as the pointer" magic [only happens for arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array).

Comment: Write down your home address on a piece of paper. Let's call this paper `p`. Now consider the difference between the address you wrote down and A) the person who lives at that address (`*p`, i.e. yourself), and B) the location of the piece of paper you wrote it on (`&p`, probably your desk or some other flat surface).

Comment: The first expression `*p` causes undefined behaviour, because `p` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain me why &p have the same address after I allocated memory.

You cannot take the address of an object whose memory has not been allocated. The pointer is allocated at the beginning of the block scope. Therefore you never observed the address of the pointer before it was allocated - only after.

You do take the address of the pointer before the dynamic memory is allocated. After you allocate the dynamic memory, you assign the value of the pointer to have the address of the dynamic memory. Assigning the value of a variable has no effect on where that variable is stored. It is expected to remain in the same address.

---

> And why p does not have the same address as: &p ?

You never observe the address of `&p`. In fact, `&p` is a temporary, so it has no address.

`<< &p` gives you the value of `&p` i.e. the address of `p`. `<< p` gives you the value of `p` i.e. an indeterminate value on the first occasion, and the address of the dynamically allocated integer on the second occasion.

Perhaps you meant to ask "why `p` does not have the same **value** as `&p`". That is simply because `p` doesn't point to itself, but to another object instead.

---

Also, reading an indeterminate value has undefined behaviour. Your program reads `p`, and also dereferences it before assigning it a value. Therefore the behaviour of your program is undefined.

---

> reference address

Your program uses no references.

---

> What is a reference then?

Reference is a type similar to a pointer. It is simpler and more restricted: It can not be null, it can not be re-assigned and its address can not be taken. Whenever a reference variable is used, it is indirected implicitly, unlike a pointer that must be dereferenced explicitly. Example:

```
int  i;        // non reference, non pointer
int* p = &i;   // a pointer
int& r = i;    // a reference

p = nullptr;   // a pointer can be null (doesn't point to anything)
               // and it can be reassigned
//r = nullptr; // a reference can not. This is ill-formed
r   = 42;      // a reference is implicitly indirected
*p  = 42;      // a pointer must be dereferenced explicitly
               // to acces the pointed object


int** pp = &p;   // you can take the address of a pointer
//int*& pr = &r; // you cannot take the address of a reference
p = &r;          // if you apply address-of operator on a reference,
                 // it is indirected implicitly
```

Comment: What is a reference then? I want to know clearly... I am a bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

`&p` contains the address of `p`.

`p` contains the address of the value; this can change when you re-allocate.

`*p` dereferences the address and reads/writes the value.

Besides your code is not correct; it might compile though.

Answer (score 0):

variable `p` holds a pointer to an integer, i.e. the value of `p` is a pointer, and this value changes when you assign `p = new int`;

`&p`, in contrast, means the memory address where `p` stores this pointer value. The address `&p` is most likely on the stack, and this address does not change if you assign something to `p`.

Note further that your first `cout`-sequence refers to non-initialized variables, which is undefined behaviour.