# What's the type difference between a, &a, and &a[0]?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

void arrayFunctionA(int* p)
{
}

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {7, 7, 7};
    arrayFunctionA(a);
    arrayFunctionA(&a[0]);
    arrayFunctionA(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

This will not compile, with an error on `arrayFunctionA(&a);`.

So, `a` and `&a[0]` evaluates as `int*`, but `&a` does not.

What is the distinction between these 3?

Comment: Very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array

Comment: `&a[0]` isn't really that useful for an `int[]`. It's typically used to unbox a pointer to the underlying buffer in a `std::vector<int>`, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is an array of 3 `int` type (`int [3]`).

A fixed array decays to a pointer to its first element, so in `arrayFunctionA(a)`, `a` will decay into an `int*` pointer to it's first element.

`&a[0]` is the address of the array's first element, and is of type `int *`.

`&a` is the address of the array itself, and is of type `int (*)[3]` (pointer to an array of 3 `int`).

So, for a function with signature

```
void arrayFunctionA(int* p);
```

Passing `a` or `&a[0]` will serve the same purpose, while passing `&a` will result in an incompatibility between the passed argument value and the function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The first two examples are identical.

- In the first one, `a` decays to a pointer and binds to the `int*` taken by the function.
- In the second one, `&a[0]` is identical to `&*(p + 0)` which yields a `int*`.

The third example doesn't compile because applying the address-of operator (`&`) to an array yield a pointer to an array. In your example the result is a `int(*arr)[3]` which cannot bind to a `int*` so you get the compilation error.

Comment: I wouldn't say that `a` and `&a[0]` are _identical_, per se, but that they are both _compatible_ with the `int *` type.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, I meant the behavior is identical in the example at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Оn the first call `arrayFunctionA(a);` the actual address of `a` is being passed.

Оn the second call `arrayFunctionA(&a[0]);` the actual address of index 0 is being passed.

The first and second calls are identical. You both get the address of index 0 (remember that an array is also a pointer).

On the third call you are getting the pointer of `a` which is already a pointer.

Comment: *on the first call `arrayFunctionA(a);` the actual address of a is being passed.*: What?   
*The first and second call is identical.*: No, they are not.

Comment: You took it too far. You do not have to contact that legend in haven. We poor C learners are here to convey his message to the world. I read that and I suggest you to read that again and try to understand it correctly. `a` has to be converted to the pointer to an array of first element while `&a[0]` already is a pointer to the first element of the array. I don't know what `pa` is in your comment but I guess it is of type `int *` and in this case `pa` is already a pointer to `int`. No conversion is happening. If `pa` is an array then `pa=&a[0]` wrong.

Comment: They will have identical value but that doesn't make `a` and `&a[0]` identical. Even `&a` will have same value as `a` and `&a[0]`, do you think `&a` is identical to the former two?