# How the pointer and the pointer's adress can share the same memory adress?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

In this code, I have read that `ar` is equivalent to `&ar[0]`, so we can write `int* pointer = ar;` while working with pointers .It seems `ar` is a pointer to `ar[0]`. So how `&ar` and `ar` can be same? Isn't `ar`a pointer to `ar[0]` and `&ar` is the memory location of the pointer `ar`?

```
int ar[3] = {1,2,3};
cout<<ar<<endl;
cout<<&ar<<endl;
```

Comment: They yield the same. However, `&ar[0]+1` will yield something different than `&ar+1`. (Try it!)

Comment: Pointer to the first array element (obtained either explicitly `&ar[0]` or implicitly `ar`) and pointer to the whole array (`&ar`) point to the same memory location. Note that in `&ar` array is not implicitly converted to pointer to first element, `ar` stays an array.

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412694/address-of-array

Comment: `ar` is not a pointer. So question is more like "How an array and the array's address can share the same value?"

Comment: Note that `"cout<<ar<<endl;
cout<<&ar<<endl;"` could print out different text, yet refer to the same address.  To see if pointers refer to the same address, use `==`: `"cout<< (ar == &ar)<<endl;`.

Answer (score 4):

1. `&ar` is the address of the array, its type is "pointer to an array of three integers".
2. `ar`, when passed to the ostream decays to a pointer to its first element, which is of type "pointer to integer". The same happens when it is assigned to an according pointer.
3. When printing pointers, other than those to `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`, the pointers are converted to "pointer to void".

In summary, printing the array or printing the address of the first element generates the same output, because the address of the array is also the address of the first element. Their types differ, but that is irrelevant because they are converted to void anyway.

Comment: So ar is not a pointer initally. It just decays to it when called, so what is it when it is not decayed?

Comment: @Crazy_Boy53 Without decay it's simply an array. The type of it is `int[3]`.

Comment: `ar` is an array. Use e.g. `sizeof` to get its size or `typeid` to explore this further.

Comment: `cout<<(ar + 1)<<endl;
cout<<(&ar+1)<<endl;` is illustrative to add to show type difference.

Comment: I suppose ar + 1 is &ar[1], and what does &ar + 1 correspond to?

Comment: `&ar + 1` is evaluated as `(&ar) + 1`, so it takes the address and then performs pointer arithmetic on it. In short, it's the address of the first byte behind the array and the type is `pointer to array of three integers`.