# Lvalue and Rvalue with C++ arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I have done some experimentation on array and learning about L-value and R-values,

From my understanding:

> L-values are object that has an identifiable memory location, R-values are defined by exclusion, anything that is not a L-value, is a R-value, by exclusion.

Here is my experiment:

```
int array [] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4};            
std::cout << array << std::endl;           //0x61fedc
std::cout << &array << std::endl;          //0x61fedc
std::cout << *(&array) << std::endl;       //0x61fedc
std::cout << *array << std::endl;          //8
```

Line 1 and 2 should come with no surprises, when you evaluate an array, it will return the address of the first element

What is confusing is the results from line 3. `*(&array)` is saying to me "what is the de-referenced value of the first memory address of the variable `array`, I was expecting `8`, however i got back the first memory address, why is that?

Lastly, line 4 evaluates to `8`, which was expected. However, since the dereferencing operator works on the `array` variable, why can't we conclude that `array` is a pointer (points to the first element memory address)? I know this can't be truth but they behaves the same?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I find an example clarifying. Here I have some `foo` overloads accepting the versions you've used in your code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<size_t N>
std::string foo(const int(&)[N]) {
    return std::string(" int(&)[") + std::to_string(N) + "]\n";
}

template<size_t N>
std::string foo(const int(*)[N]) {
    return std::string(" int(*)[") + std::to_string(N) + "]\n";
}

std::string foo(const int*) {
    return " int*\n";
}

std::string foo(int) {
    return " int\n";
}

int main() {
    int array [] = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4};
    std::cout << array     << foo(array);
    std::cout << &array    << foo(&array);
    std::cout << *(&array) << foo(*(&array));
    std::cout << *array    << foo(*array);
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x7ffeaf43a610 int(&)[5]
0x7ffeaf43a610 int(*)[5]
0x7ffeaf43a610 int(&)[5]
8 int
```

As you can see, with this combination of overloads, none of the versions decay into an `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412801/785194). Basically, sometimes an array to pointer conversion takes place, sometimes it doesn't.

Your definition of an lvalue is incorrect. An lvalue must be capable of being assigned to; it is valid on the left hand side of assignment. A read-only location has an address, for example, but is not an lvalue.

Comment: A read-only location can be an lvalue. `const int value = 5;` and `"abc"` are both read-only and lvalues (not to mention read-only lvalue references `const T&`). And rvalues can be assigned to: `std::string("aaa") = "bbb";` works fine.

Comment: @Artyer: You're going to have to back that up. 5 minutes on my bookshelf, with the Dragon book (p64/65/etc), and Mitchell (p118), make it clear that you have to be able to store something in an lvalue. Initialisation is not the same thing. I have also written 2 compilers.

Comment: From the C++ (17) standard 6.10 [basic.lval]: "A glvalue is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function". (basically has an address). In the example in the other comment, `value` is a read-only lvalue, and `"abc"` is the identity of a static storage duration `const char[4]` (And also 8.1.1 [expr.prim.literal] in the standard says clearly: "A string literal is an lvalue"). Also `std::string("aaa")` is an rvalue, since there is no object for it to be the identity of until it is created by tempory materialisation, but it can be assigned to.

Comment: Also the standard states than every expression must be an lvalue, xvalue or prvalue. An expression that evaluates to something with the address of a read-only location would have to be an lvalue or xvalue (a glvalue), otherwise it wouldn't have an address.